# How to run C++program at the backend of a web application?

Tags: c++, backend, web-development-server

I have an algorithm which is written in C++. No, I wanted to create a front end web app through which I can take inputs and then execute my c++ program with this input at the backend. How can I do so?

Comment: It's absolutely possible in pure C++, but I see you're a beginner, so it'll take you eternity to set up a backend in C++. You may try to find a library to ease it a bit, or write the frontend-backend in more high-level language, like Java/Python

Comment: Look up CGI for C++ , e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Comment: You usually write a daemon application that runs as a background process and implements the algorithm in C++. Then you do requests from frontend to backend over HTTP or some other protocol.

Comment: The options are many. You could make a [c++ addon for node](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#c-addonshttps://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#c-addons), and use a node backend that calls your c++ module.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a backend web application using a framework like [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib).

For example, the following endpoint `/numbers` takes in numbers in its url path

```cpp
#include <httplib.h>

int main(void)
{
        using namespace httplib;

        Server svr;

        svr.Get(R"(/numbers/(\d+))", [&](const Request &req, Response &res)
                {
                auto numbers = req.matches[1];
                res.set_content(numbers, "text/plain");
            });

        svr.Get("/stop", [&](const Request &req, Response &res)
                { svr.stop(); });

        svr.listen("localhost", 6000);
}
```